# Vectorize loop in R

Tags: r, loops, vectorization

I have some array named `P_Array` with 100,000 data points and need to calculate the first order autocorrelation for subintervalls of length 100, i.e. from `1:100` and `2:101` etc. I've written a loop which works just fine, but is very slow.

```
Tf <- 100000
acf_Array <- rep(0, length.out = Tf-100)  
for (t in 1:(Tf-100)){
  acf_Array[t] <- acf(P_Array[t:(t+100)])$acf[2]
  }
```

My idea was to use something like

```
acf_Array[1:(Tf-100)] <- acf(P_Array[(1:(Tf-100)):(101:Tf)])$acf[2]
```

which, however, does not work. Any suggestions?

### Edit

I think this will do the trick

```
  for (t in 1:(Tf-100)){
  acf_Array[t] <- cor(P_Array[t:(t+98)], P_Array[(t+1):(t+99)])
  }
```

Comment: Your speed-limiting part of the code are the many, many calls to acf. I'm not sure if this can be avoided, so I can only suggest writing a faster `acf` function (that only calculates the second coefficient and maybe avoids some unnecessary tests) or translating the whole loop into compiled code via Rcpp.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the specific question on vectorising the for loop, this is my answer:

```
acf_Array <- sapply(1:Tf-100, function(x) acf(P_Array[x:x+100])$acf[2])
```

But as mentioned in the comments the speed limiting bit is probably the `acf` function.

Comment: This is not an answer, but a suggestion. You should post this as a comment under the main question.

Comment: This is not an example of vectorization. `*apply` functions are just hidden loops. They are often recommended because they are more convenient and more readable, but they are not faster than a well written `for` loop.